# Adding timer for asnwer

Tags: python, timer

I would like to add timer to my quiz. Here is an example how I am trying to do that using th.Timer but cannot figure out why is it not working.

```
from time import *
import threading as th


if answer == question["prawidlowa_odpowiedz"] and S.is_alive():
        points += 1
        total_points += 1
        print("Brawo, prawidłowa odpowiedź, twój aktualny wynik:", points, "/", total_points, "punktów")
    else:
        total_points += 1
        print("Zła odpowiedź, twój aktualny wynik:", points, "/", total_points, "punktów")


def sctn():
    pass


while True:
     if len(the_filenames) != 0:
         random_section = random.choice(the_filenames)
         print()
         print("Wylosowano dział:", random_section[:-5])
            with open(r"C:\Users\Tymek\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\quiz!\ematyka\\" + random_section) as file:
                questions = json.load(file)
                the_filenames.remove(random_section)
                i = []
                for i in range(0, len(questions)):
                    S = th.Timer(20, sctn)
                    S.start()
                    show_questions(questions[i])
                    S.cancel()
                    print("Twój aktualny wynik to:", points, "/", total_points)
```

Comment: There are libraries for that e.g. https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ Schedule a job and compare timestamps (reset on new question)